# Python Tkinter read only text field

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

How can I create a text field in Tkinter where my mouse pointer becomes active to select and copy that text content, like in the following screenshot?

[image: Example]

It is a Windows media player song properties window.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the state of `Text` to disabled:

```
root = tkinter.Tk()
input = tkinter.Text(root)
input.configure(state=tkinter.DISABLED)
```

And to enable it again:

```
input.configure(state=tkinter.NORMAL)
```

You could also set the styling, to make it look more like your screenshot:

```
input.configure(state=tkinter.DISABLED,
    borderwidth=0,
    background=root.cget('background'))
```

And to add text:

```
input.insert(tkinter.END, "I'd like to suggest that coconuts migrate.")
```

Also see: [Methods on Text widgets](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/text-methods.html).

Comment: @user2332665 Use the `insert()` method; I've updated my answer with an example (this info was also in the link I posted, by the way).

Comment: @user2332665 Right. You usually want `tk.END`, which means "append to end". But you do a lot more, [here's a full description](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/text-index.html) if the index parameter.

Comment: How should I update the content in the Text widget. For eg, I have an Entry widget that takes an integer and a Button upon pressing will display multiplication table of that integer on the Text field(only multiplication table of current integer). Should I delete the Text widget and create a fresh one with new data.

Comment: You should be able to use `input.delete(0, tkinter.END)` to remove the contents. (not tested, [lifted from this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2260235/how-to-clear-the-entry-widget-in-a-gui-after-a-button-is-pressed-in-python/2262084#2262084))

Comment: once we use `input.configure(state=tkinter.DISABLED)` the widget is disabled for ever, we can't use `input.delete(0, tkinter.END)`, or any further updation on it. what I did for updating is creating the same widget(fresh) again..