# python clearing text box with button event

Tags: python, events, tkinter

I am trying to clear the text box i typed already with a Button 'Clear'.But its not clearing the text once the button is clicked!

Please fix my problem!Answer will be appreciated!

```
import tkinter as tki

class App(object):

    def __init__(self,root):
        self.root = root
        txt_frm = tki.Frame(self.root, width=600, height=400)
        txt_frm.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
        # ensure a consistent GUI size
        txt_frm.grid_propagate(False)

        self.txt1 = tki.Text(txt_frm, borderwidth=3, relief="sunken", height=4,width=55)
        self.txt1.config(font=("consolas", 12), undo=True, wrap='word')
        self.txt1.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew", padx=2, pady=2)

        button1 = tki.Button(txt_frm,text="Clear", command = self.clearBox)
        button1.grid(column=2,row=0)
    def clearBox(self):
        self.txt1.delete(0, END)

root = tki.Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: im sorry,it doesnot generate error but its not clearing once clicked!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to clear the entry widget in a GUI after a button is pressed in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2260235/how-to-clear-the-entry-widget-in-a-gui-after-a-button-is-pressed-in-python)

Comment: indent your code properly please and also there is no `txt1` in your code right now.

Comment: One additional thing is, you `pack`ed your frame but used `grid_propogate`.

Comment: now i edited my code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `END` is in tkinter you need to use `tki.END` or `"end"` (with quotes, lower case) also your starting index should be `"1.0"`(thanks to BryanOakley) instead of `0`.

This one should work.

```
def clearBox(self):
    self.txt1.delete("1.0", "end")
```

**EDIT**: By the way it will be better if you use `pack_propagate` instead of `grid_propagate` since you used `pack` to place your frame.

**EDIT2**: About that index thing, it is written in [here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm) under lines and columns section.

> ...Line numbers start at 1, while column numbers start at 0...
>
> Note that line/column indexes may look like floating point values, but it’s seldom possible to treat them as such (consider position 1.25 vs. 1.3, for example). I sometimes use 1.0 instead of “1.0” to save a few keystrokes when referring to the first character in the buffer, but that’s about it.

Comment: `0` and `0.0` are both invalid starting indexes. The first character in a text widget is `"1.0"` and the index should be a string, not a floating point number.

Comment: @BryanOakley that is weird because 0.0 is working for me right now but if you say so, it is probably true. :D

Comment: @Lafexlos: 0.0 works, but only because the developers were liberal in what they accept, and `0.0` gets translated to `"1.0"` internally. A proper index is a string of the form _line.column_, with lines starting at 1 and columns starting at zero. That's the documented format.

Comment: @BryanOakley After you pointed out, I searched a bit and added those information as edit. Thanks for the heads up.