# Label inside Entry in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry, tkinter-button, tkinter-label

I have a searchbox that is an Entry in tkinter and I want to have an X-button in the right corner that the user can click on and it will delete everything that was typed in the box. But I cannot fin a solution on how to put a Label or Button inside Entry. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

this is an oop solution, init function creates widgets and the clear function deletes the text inside the entry. You can arrange the position of the widgets with `pack()`, `grid()` would also work.

here is a similar question: [How to clear the Entry widget after a button is pressed in Tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2260235/how-to-clear-the-entry-widget-after-a-button-is-pressed-in-tkinter)

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.entryText = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.entryText.pack()
        self.XButton = ttk.Button(self, text="X-Button", command=self.clear_text).pack()

    def clear_text(self):
        self.entryText.delete(0, 'end')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry('200x100')
    App(root).pack()
    root.mainloop()
```